# Javascript pass var value using innerHTML, fire Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, variables, innerhtml

1. I have two input boxes with their own ID
2. I pull whatever is typed into those input boxes by their ID into javascript
3. I decide which one of the two I want and spit it out to the screen with innerHTML
4. Now I have a div with and ID and it is showing the innerHTML var

All this works what I can't figure out is...

Five. Bring that innerHTML var back to javascript

Is it possible?

Hope this makes sense to someone.  Thanks.

Comment: won't repeating the process cause the same result? Or you mean that you want to repeat the process after inputting a new amount?

Comment: Once either taco1 or taco2 moves on to the next step.  They will be compared to taco3 and which ever one of those has a higher cost will move on again. It is basically a tournament bracket.

Comment: Can you provide us with a example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I just got a different example and modded it a bit. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/5434/
If you click go you see taco1 and taco2 show up and then from there (on my page you enter a number) whatever number is higher taco1 or taco2 will post again to the screen further down.  It does nothing in that example though...